# IIS Slows down when to many long running requests in .Net

Tags: iis, iis-10

I have an API Service, that sometimes takes a while to spit out the answer, like maybe 120 to 200 seconds. Most of the time the answer will be produced in 1 to 5 seconds.

When there are let's say 20 requests to IIS that have long-running answers between 120 - 200 seconds. All the other incoming requests seem to take much longer to process and everything gets real slow until those 20 requests produce results.

I have the application pool set 50,000 concurrent requests, but I see this behaviour with as little as 100 x 200 requests and then the requests keep growing until the long running ones complete.

I was under the impression that all requests will run normally and independently of one another. And a few shouldn't slow down the rest. The CPU on the machine never churns over 1%.

Is there anything I might be overlooking? Configuration wise?

**After reading lex li answer, and setting the max worker threads might help, how many CPU's is this considered?**

And how many worker threads will this enable?

```
<processModel autoConfig="false" requestQueueLimit="100000" maxWorkerThreads="200" maxIoThreads="200" minWorkerThreads="50" minIoThreads="50" />
```

[image: How many CPU's is this?]

And how many under this scenario?

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what ASP.NET programming model does not well support https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/821268/ You need to redesign your app to get rid of those long running bits (moving to a separate process via message queue or other IPCs).

Comment: @LexLi I edited my question, can you provide further information.